# Enthalpy/Temperature change in a chemical reaction

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, enthalpy, heat

I was wondering how exactly absolute temperature change in a chemical reaction could be calculated.
For example, consider this reaction:

3H₂+N₂→2NH₃, ΔH=-46kJ/mol (298.15K)

Assuming the given reaction goes to 100% completion (which it doesn't, it's the Fritz-Haber reaction, but this is a theroretical question), and is conducted at 298.15K and 1 atm of pressure, so that the enthalpy change is -46kJ/mol, how can we calculate the temperature change?

My thought was that we divide the reaction into two steps of thought; first we let three moles of hydrogen (at 298.15K) and one mole of nitrogen (also at 298.15K) react and form two moles of ammonia gas. The temperature stays at 298.15K, so the two moles of ammonia also are at 298.15K. (Is that correct?)

Then, in a second step (assuming we have a closed container and the released heat is again absorbed by the products) we just add 2 times 46kJ to the products,(correction: 1 times 46kJ) so this problem reduces to a simple heat capacity problem. So Cp(NH3)=35.06kJ/molK roughly, so the temperature of the 2 moles of NH3 should increase from 298.15K to 299.46K.

As I explained, I am absolutely unsure if we can even calculate it like that, so any help would really be appreciated, maybe other examples and sources, too.

Comment: This is correct if the reaction is carried out at constant pressure, except that, in step 2, you only add 1*46 kJ to the products.  And also, that's 46 kJ, not 46 J.

Comment: Ah thank you. That is because it is 46 kJ per mole of reaction right? Not mole of products

Comment: Yes, that is correct.